# How to convert shp to PostGIS dump?

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis, shapefile, kmz

**Given a shp file** such those from Gadm [e.g. US administrative divisions](http://www.filefactory.com/file/5xkecujkx4sd/n/USA_adm_zip), where the coordinate reference system is latitude/longitude with WGS84 datum.

Input could actually be:

1. Shapefile,
2. ESRI personal geodatabase,
3. ESRI file geodatabase,
4. Google Earth .kmz,
5. R (SpatialPolygonsDataFrame)

**How to convert this input into a WGS84 PostGIS dump ?**

Comment: With specialised GIS-focused questions like this that aren't really programming as such, I suggest trying http://gis.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: This ogr2ogr may help as well: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/7851/19460

Comment: Not about programming, but reasonable; belongs on gis.stackexchange.com but no migration option to it is available in voting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gis.stackexchange.com cite [an ogr2ogr way](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68417/) which may works :

```
ogr2ogr -overwrite -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=myhost user=myuser dbname=mydb password=mypass" my_file.shp
```

Answer (score 2):

For shapefiles, use the `shp2pgsql` tool provided by PostGIS.

You'll probably need different tools for the other different formats. [Here's one of many references on PostGIS Data import](http://www.wildsong.biz/index.php/Loading_data_into_PostGIS). It mentions `ogr2ogr` in particular.

Finally, there'll probably be better-informed answers on the [repost of this question on gis.stackexchange.com](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/68417/12379).